# hibernate criteria putting a contains / does not contain restriction on a set of elements

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Hi I'm trying to migrate my old sql based query framework to be Hibernate Criteria based, currently I'm using Hibernate version 3.2. and mysql v 5.0.54

My question is I want to write a criteria that returns all the Beans that **do not** have a value in a contained set of elements.

A summary of the hibernate config file for the bean is:

```
    <hibernate-mapping package="com.mydomain.beans">

       <typedef class="com.mydomain.dao.util.HibernateAgentOptionType" name="agent-option"/>

       <class name="Agent" table="agent">
           ...
           <set name="agentOptions" table="agent_options" fetch="join" lazy="true">
              <key column="agt_id"/>
              <element column="identifier" type="agent-option"/>
           </set>
       </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
```

The class file is something like:

```
public class Agent {
   ...
   public Set<Option> getAgentOptions() {
      return agentOptions;
   }
   public void setAgentOptions(Set<Option> _agentOptions) {
      this.agentOptions = _agentOptions;
   }

   public enum Option {
      WEB_SITE_SYNDICATE ("web-site-syndicate"),
      RECEIVE_PREMIUM_ENQUIRIES ("receive-premium-enquiries"), 
      DO_NOT_SYNDICATE_ADS_TO_THIRD_PARTIES ("do-not-syndicate-ads-to-third-parties")
   }
}
```

I would like to retrieve all the agents who **do not have** the Option "DO_NOT_SYNDICATE_ADS_TO_THIRD_PARTIES" in their agentOptions

the sql that I was using for this previously was something like:

```
SELECT agt.id 
FROM agent agt
WHERE agt.id NOT IN (
   SELECT sub_agt.id FROM agent sub_agt 
   JOIN agent_options AS agt_options ON agt_options.agt_id = sub_agt.id
   WHERE agt_options.identifier = 'do_not_syndicate_ads_to_third_parties'
)
```

I've tried this:

```
   ...
   Criteria crit = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(Agent.class);
   crit.addRestriction(Restriction.not(Restriction.in("agentOptions", noSyndicatedAds)));
   ...
```

Which spits out bad sql

I've also tried this using aliases:

```
   ...
   crit.createAlias("agentOptions", "agentOption");
   crit.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("agentOption", options)));
   ...
```

Which throws an exception:

org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an association: Agent.agentOptions

Finally I decided to try a brute sql Criterion:

```
...
   crit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(" {alias}.id not in " +
               "(select agt_sub.id " +
               "from agent agt_sub " +
               "join agent_options as agent_options_sub on agent_options_sub.agt_id = agt_sub.id " +
               "where agent_options_sub.identifier in (?)) ",
               Agent.Option.DO_NOT_SYNDICATE_ADS_TO_THIRD_PARTIES.getIdentifier(),
               new org.hibernate.type.StringType()
         ));
   ...
```

Which worked but seems a little bit ugly.

Does anyone know if there is a way using the std Criteria API without having to resort to sql.

Any help or suggestions would be very welcome.  Even if they require upgrading to a more recent version of Hibernate.

Cheers
Simon

Comment: I would also like to know.  I have a parent entity with a Set of children that have a "description" field.  I'm trying to write a DAO function that would bring back all the parents whose children's descriptions match some search text (using like/ilike.)  I was able to get it "working" but it adds a second join to the child table, which the mapping adds.  I guess I really just want to add a restriction to the join that's already occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your subquery as a `DetachedCriteria`, and then use your nested `Restrictions` to achieve  a `NOT IN`.  In your case:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Agent.class);
subquery.createAlias("agentOptions", "agentOption");
subbquery.add(Restrictions.eq("identifier", Agent.Option.DO_NOT_SYNDICATE_ADS_TO_THIRD_PARTIES.getIdentifier());
subquery.setProjection(Projections.property("agt_id")); // only return one field
crit.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("agt_id", subquery)));
```